# Is this comparative always applicable? as + much + adjective + a/an + noun + as

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In my schoolbook there are three **as ... as** grammatical structures introduced:

> as + adjective + as
>
> as + adverb + as
>
> as + much/many + noun + as

What bothers me, is the last one.
What if I want to say:

> He gave **as much accurate an answer as** he could.

This structure appeared when we were doing CAE, Part 4, and this was the following sentence:

> *He answered the judge's question as accurately as he could.*
>
> **ACCURATE**
>
> *He gave ... as he could to the judge's question.*

[This](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-as) is the best source I can find (it's from Cambridge), however, it hasn't mentioned this structure and I want to teach it to my CAE students as we have come across it in transformations (as the aforementioned one). Can you help me find a source that explicitly says this is the structure we need to use for the situation?

Comment: This would be [as + much/many + adjective + a/n + noun + as] and is ungrammatical. You require 'He gave as accurate an answer as possible.' / 'It was as green a field as you're ever likely to see.' etc

Comment: The answer key actually said this structure is the only correct one possible - my students had to transform this sentence:

"He answered the judge's question as accurately as he could. -> He gave as much accurate an answer as he could to the judge's question."

Comment: The answer key is incorrect if that is actually what it claims.  Try googling "as much accurate an answer" and "as accurate an answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having comes from two separate issues.

First, [accurate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accurate) is not a noun; it's an adjective.  So the "as + (adjective) + as" structure is the one you want here.

> He gave *as accurate as*...

Whoops! Now we've run into our second problem; adjectives need a noun to modify.  But "answer" is not the subject of the sentence you're wanting to build, so that's not quite right either.  What you want is to add "answer" between the two *as*'s.

> He gave *as accurate an answer as* he could to the judge's question.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I have mentioned in the description, with the only difference that I have "much" in front of the adjective and that I need an actual source so that I can justify the indefinite article in front of the noun.

Comment: "Much accurate" isn't grammatical because "accurate" is an adjective, not a noun.  What I was trying to point out was that your use of the "as much (noun) as" structure isn't appropriate here.